# If an exception is thrown in the @BeforeEach method, will @AfterEach still run

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

In my tests, I have data setup (which is a series of different entities) that happens in the @BeforeEach method. I clean up that data in the @AfterEach method. Now if an exception were to be thrown during the creation of any of those entities, will the @AfterEach method run? Currently I have a workaround with a try/catch block in my @BeforeEach method, but it would reduce some code duplication if the @AfterEach method takes care of it for me.

Comment: Why would you ever assume that the `@BeforeEach`-method throws an exception? At this point, the tests seem broken or ill-designed.

Comment: Please, add details: do you create entities in database? if yes, which one, do you perform commit?

Answer (score 3):

So after further testing, the `@AfterEach` method runs after the `@BeforeEach` method in the event an exception occurs in the `@BeforeEach` method. The `@BeforeEach` method is doing data setup in the DB. It run a series of API calls to create all the data which is persisted in the DB. Then the test runs, followed by the `@AfterEach` method.
If an exception occurs while creating an entity, the `@BeforeEach` method terminates, the `@AfterEach` method is invoked which cleans up any created entities.